# Flash Builder 4.7 add global external .as source

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I've been always using FlashDevelop as my IDE to build Air mobile projects and I have created a folder somewhere on my drive and have put all the .as classes that I use between my projects there. in FLashDevelop you have the option to address to this folder and you will be able to import them and use them. no matter how many projects you create, the .as files are shared between them so if I change one class it will reflect on all other projects also...

recently, one of my clients asked me to help him with a Flash Builder project... I was able to understand how to create a mobile project and import and use .ane files in it all fine.

what I never managed to find out after hours of Googling was how to set a global address to my .as folder where I have all my classes?

please note, I do not want to add .swc to my project but actually the raw .as files.

any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Add an external resource folder to the source path**

Select the project in the Package Explorer.
Select Project > Properties > ActionScript Build Path
On the build path properties page, select the Source Path tab.
Click the Add Folder button.
Enter or and browse to the folder’s path, and click OK.
The folder is added to the source path.

You can also use the Source Path properties tab to edit, delete, or reorder items in the source path.

Folders that are added to the source path are marked in the Package Explorer.